# Is extracting files from a zip archive faster than copying files from the same archive?

Tags: file-transfer, zip, archiving

Say we have a .zip archive with some number of files inside.

Previously, I've opened the archive (and the folder of the same name inside, why do they always do that?) and dragged the files to another folder, essentially copying the files.

Now, say I right click and extract the archive's contents to the same folder, rather than the drag/copy operation.

Which one runs faster?

Comment: Copying by dragging extracts the files, so they're the same thing. It only depends if you're extracting all files or just certain files within the archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between copying files from a zip file (or any archive) or extracting them.  The reason is, copying the files still requires the files to be extracted and decompressed.  The same amount of work and time will be needed for both to accomplish the same task.